# R: Automatically Storing the Results of a Graph into a Table

Tags: r, dplyr, onclick, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to learn how to store the results of a (interactive) graph into a table. Using the following code, I generated some data and made the desired interactive graphs:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

#generate data
set.seed(123)

var = rnorm(731, 100,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

vals <- 90:100
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
    
    data$var_i = i
    data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
    
    #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
    aggregate_i = data %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i),  median = median(new_var_i))
    
    #combine files together
    
    aggregate_i$var = i
    aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
    
    count <- count + 1
    combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
    
}

result_1 <- bind_rows(combine)
result_1$group = "group_a"
result_1$group = as.factor(result_1$group)


gg <-ggplot(result_1, aes(frame = var, color = group)) + geom_line(aes(x=month, y=mean, group=1))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + ggtitle("graph1")

gg = ggplotly(gg)

######

var = rnorm(731, 85,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

vals <- 90:100
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
    
    data$var_i = i
    data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
    
    #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
    aggregate_i = data %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i), median = median(new_var_i))
    
    #combine files together
    
    aggregate_i$var = i
    aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
    
    count <- count + 1
    combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
    
}

result_2 <- bind_rows(combine)
result_2$group = "group_b"
result_2$group = as.factor(result_2$group)


gg1 <-ggplot(result_2, aes(frame = var, color = group)) + geom_line(aes(x=month, y=mean, group=1))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + ggtitle("graph2")

gg1 = ggplotly(gg1)

#combine graphs
sub = subplot(gg, gg1, nrows = 2)
#view final graph
sub
```

[image]

My goal: from here, every time the user "drags the slider" to a new value, I am trying to store the means and medians of both graphs into a small table.

[image]

Using the dplyr library in R, I was able to create a large table that stores the means and medians for both graphs, for all possible values of the "var" variable. The idea being, this large table will populate the smaller table for a given value of "var":

```
    fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'table',
  columnwidth = c(100, 100),
  columnorder = c(0, 1),
  header = list(
    values = c("average","group"),
    align = c("center", "center"),
    line = list(width = 1, color = 'black'),
    fill = list(color = c("grey", "grey")),
    font = list(family = "Arial", size = 14, color = "white")
  ),
  cells = list(
    values = rbind(result_1$mean, result_1$median, result_1$var, result_2$mean, result_2$median, result_2$var),
    align = c("center", "center"),
    line = list(color = "black", width = 1),
    font = list(family = "Arial", size = 12, color = c("black"))
  ))

#I am not sure why the names of the columns are not appearing properly
fig
```

Now, is there a way to combine everything together? I want to store the final file in a html format:

[image]

Could someone please show me how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For logging the user's slider selections you can save your reactive value as a global variable, which will be deleted when the Shiny app stops running. Before the app closes your user can download the values with Shiny's [downloadButton()](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadButton.html) and [downloadHandler()](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadHandler.html) functions.